# Custom alert sound in pinescript

Tags: pine-script

Please see this image bellow there is the option to change sound like thin, hard bell etc.
But i want to add it in pine script so bell sound auto set via pine script.
And if it possible to add custom mp3 sound in my pine script. so it will directly trigger the sound. no need to modify manually.
I use it like that way

```
alert("New label: " + hhlltxt, alert.freq_once_per_bar) // added string
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1VAF.png

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. The sound property is not accessible via pinescript.

There are only two arguments in `alert()`.

```
alert(message, freq) → void
```

> ***message (series string)*** Message sent when the alert triggers. Required argument.
>
> ***freq (input string)*** The triggering frequency. Possible values are: alert.freq_all (all function calls trigger the alert),
> alert.freq_once_per_bar (the first function call during the bar
> triggers the alert), alert.freq_once_per_bar_close (the function call
> triggers the alert only when it occurs during the last script
> iteration of the real-time bar, when it closes). The default is
> alert.freq_once_per_bar.